# Dart accessing the name of a File or Directory

Tags: dart

How do I read the name of a File or a Directory?

There is a property 'path' but that returns the entire file path.

Would be nice to have a property like 'name' that just returns the last part of the path.

In Java there is a method called File.name();

Comment: BTW please consider to validate answers to your questions.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the [path package](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/path) to do that :

```dart
import 'package:path/path.dart' as path;
main() {
  path.basename('path/to/foo.dart'); // -> 'foo.dart'
  path.basename('path/to');          // -> 'to'
}
```

See the [path package documentation](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/path.html) for more explanations.

Answer (score 4):

Since Dart Version `2.6` has been announced and it's available for flutter version `1.12` and higher, You can use `extension` methods. It will provide a more readable and global solution to this problem.

`file_extensions.dart` :

```
import 'dart:io';

extension FileExtention on FileSystemEntity{
  String get name {
    return this?.path?.split("/")?.last;
  }
}
```

and `name` getter is added to all the file objects. You can simply just call `name` on any file.

```
main() {
  File file = new File("/dev/dart/work/hello/app.dart");
  print(file.name);
}
```

Read the [document](https://dart.dev/guides/language/extension-methods) for more information.

**Note:**
Since `extension` is a new feature, it's not fully integrated into IDEs yet and it may not be recognized automatically. You have to import your `extension` manually wherever you need that. Just make sure the extension file is imported:

```
import 'package:<your_extention_path>/file_extentions.dart';
```